# rails 3 pass params into partial with haml and unobtrusive javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, unobtrusive-javascript

How to pass params into partial with haml and unobtrusive javascript

comments/create.js.haml

```
$("#comment_list").html("#{escape_javascript( render(:partial => "shared/comments", :locals => { :commentable => @album }) ).html_safe}");
```

crashed

but  in albums/show.html.haml

```
#comment_list= render :partial => 'shared/comments', :locals => { :commentable => @album }
```

working without bugs

Comment: do you have `:javascript` tag ?

Comment: I was add :javascript tag Showing /home/slavik/ror/mebel/app/views/comments/create.js.haml where line #1 raised:

`Filter "javacript" is not defined.`
Extracted source (around line #1):

`1: :javacript
2:   $("#comment_list").html("#{escape_javascript( render(:partial => "shared/comments", :locals => { :commentable => @album }) ).html_safe}");`

Comment: if you add `= h Haml::Filters.defined.inspect`, `= h Haml.version.inspect` in your template, what do you get?

Comment: {"maruku"=>Haml::Filters::Maruku, "plain"=>Haml::Filters::Plain, "redcloth"=>Haml::Filters::Textile, "textile"=>Haml::Filters::Textile, "sass"=>Haml::Filters::Sass, "preserve"=>Haml::Filters::Preserve, "css"=>Haml::Filters::Css, "markdown"=>Haml::Filters::Markdown, "cdata"=>Haml::Filters::Cdata, "escaped"=>Haml::Filters::Escaped, "javascript"=>Haml::Filters::Javascript, "ruby"=>Haml::Filters::Ruby, "erb"=>Haml::Filters::ERB} {:minor=>1, :teeny=>2, :number=>"3.1.2", :name=>"Separated Sally", :string=>"3.1.2 (Separated Sally)", :major=>3}

Comment: there is a similar thread in google groups https://groups.google.com/d/topic/haml/E-D-cE-9QM8/discussion have you checked it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm change

```
#comment_list= render :partial => 'shared/comments', :locals => { :commentable => @album }
```

to

```
#comment_list= render :partial => 'shared/comments', :locals => { :commentable => @commentable }
```

and install Haml v3.1.2